# Create XML file in php using DOMDocument()

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I want to create XML file in php and I have saved the values from array to variable

```
<?php
$name = $e['name_1'];
$email = $e['email_id'];
$phone_no =$e['phone_no'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$ele1 = $doc->createElement('StudentName');
$ele1->nodeValue=$name;
$doc->appendChild($ele1);

$ele2 = $doc->createElement('FatherEmailId');
$ele2->nodeValue=$email;
$doc->appendChild($ele2);

$ele3 = $doc->createElement('PhoneNumber');
$ele3->nodeValue=$phone_no;
$doc->appendChild($ele3);

$doc->save('MyXmlFile007.xml');  

?>
```

i want my XML formatted lik this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StudentDetails>
<StudentName>Pravin Parayan</StudentName>
<FatherEmailId>pravinp@pigtailpundits.com</FatherEmailId>
<PhoneNumber>9000012345</PhoneNumber>
<StudentDetails/>
```

But instead of the above i get something lik this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StudentDetails/>
<StudentName>Joel George</StudentName>
<FatherEmailId>joy@pigtailpundits.com</FatherEmailId>
<PhoneNumber>9000012345</PhoneNumber>
```

Comment: Can you share your data array, which you used to create xml document

Comment: I misplaced the data inside the XML file format.

Comment: $e = array('name_1' =>'Joel' , 'email_id' =>'joy@gmail.com','phone_no' => '9000012345' );     @user3099298

Comment: I have sorted out the database to fetch the last in data for the purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a root element StudentDetails, and append all other elements ti it, like the following:

```
<?php
$name = $e['name_1'];
$email = $e['email_id'];
$phone_no =$e['phone_no'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('StudentDetails');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$ele1 = $doc->createElement('StudentName');
$ele1->nodeValue=$name;
$root->appendChild($ele1);

$ele2 = $doc->createElement('FatherEmailId');
$ele2->nodeValue=$email;
$root->appendChild($ele2);

$ele3 = $doc->createElement('PhoneNumber');
$ele3->nodeValue=$phone_no;
$root->appendChild($ele3);

$doc->save('MyXmlFile007.xml');
```

And the result would be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<StudentDetails>
  <StudentName>Pravin Parayan</StudentName>
  <FatherEmailId>pravinp@pigtailpundits.com</FatherEmailId>
  <PhoneNumber>9000012345</PhoneNumber>
</StudentDetails>
```